# How to use functions of an object which is accessed as a parameter to a function of another class?

Tags: java, object, methods

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
public class cls1{
  public cls1(){}                        //constructor for the sending class
  String name = "foo";                   //String I wish to access
  public String sentName(){              //Method to access the string outside
    return name;
  }
}

public class cls2{                       //Class where I wish to access the name
  public String gotName(Object obj){     //Method where I wish to call the cls1 instance
    String recvName;                     
    if(obj.getClass()==cls1.class){
      recvName = obj.sentName();         //THE PROBLEM
    }
    return recvName;
  }
}
```

I do understand that the `obj` won't have the methods and variables of the cls1 till runtime, and thus can't allow for that line to compile. Is there a way to achieve this?

P.S. I also tried to create an instance of `cls1` in `cls2`:

```
cls1 cls1Inst;
obj=cls1Inst;
cls1Inst.sentName();
```

But this gives a nullpointer exception, maybe because I am trying to access the methods of cls1 without actually creating an instance of it (I am not very clear about nullpointer, excuse my dumbness).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where you calling `cls2.gotname(obj)`?

Comment: I will be needing that method, I have not called it here for simplicity of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object is the base class of every object. First you have to Typecast in `cls1` then `cls1` methods will be available.

Change

```
recvName = obj.sentName();
```

to

```
recvName = ((cls1)obj).sentName();
```

And in this code

```
cls1 cls1Inst;  // here it is uninitilized (null)
obj=cls1Inst;    //<------ after this statement cls1Inst will be same and null
cls1Inst.sentName();// thats why it throws null pointer exception
```

This code will work

```
cls1 cls1Inst;  // here it is uninitilized (null)
cls1Inst = (cls1)obj;    // if obj is not null then typecast it. Now it is assigned to cls1Inst
cls1Inst.sentName(); // it will work perfect file
```

**Updated**

Or you can change the function Argument type from `Object` to `cls1`. This can avoid extra check for checking class type. see code below.

```
public String gotName(cls1 obj){                     
      return obj.sentName();// No need to check class type. just return name
  }
```

Comment: That worked, thanks alot. If you can, how can you achieve the same response using the second method or its a completely off-track approach?

Comment: @ElysianStorm what do you mean by second method ? bdw see updated answer. if you have any more confusion then ask me .

Comment: Your update is what I was talking about, thanks mate!

Comment: Acutally, it would be by far better to have the correct type in the receiving method! If that is not possible, you should better check for the type as it's done in the other answer!

Comment: @jokster yeah that will be good appproach. see updated answer :) thanks

Comment: @jokster Yes, it makes more sense, thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't call sentName() on object class object. You need to typecast it to cls1 class first.

```
public class cls2{                       //Class where I wish to access the name
  public String gotName(Object obj){     //Method where I wish to call the cls1 instance
    String recvName;                     
    if(obj.getClass()==cls1.class){
      cls1 cls1Obj = (cla1)obj;
      recvName = cls1Obj.sentName();         //THE PROBLEM
    }
    return recvName;
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case, instanceof would also work and might give better results than comparing classes directly.

Comment: @jokster, agree with you.